# How to update pods to Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift3

Currently in the process of migrating to Swift 3.0. This is my first time doing anything like this and I am not entirely sure how to deal with the various pods I am using. For example I am using the pod SwiftDate: https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate. The Swift 3.0 branch isn't on the master so I assume running `pod update` won't pull the Swift 3.0 version. Am I correct in putting pod:

`'SwiftDate', :git => 'https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate.git', :branch => 'feature/swift-3.0'`

into my podfile and then running the update? Checking the github page seems this is the correct branch. Do branches only need to be specified like this when the Swift 3.0 version isn't on the master? Any tips and pointers on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: run 'pod repo update' in Terminal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all you need to update your CocaPod if you haven't done it.

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Then add the update part to your pod:

```
pod 'SwiftDate', :git => 'https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate.git', :branch => 'feature/swift-3.0'
```

Then in terminal run `pod update`

Comment: Why the --pre tag? Is this the prerelease for CocaPods?

Comment: Yes if you need it otherwise just go with `sudo gem install cocoapods`it should be fine

Comment: I believe for Alamofire it does need it. Hopefully this will fix up my errors. Exactly what I was looking for. thanks.

Comment: @Kex, For Alamofire you need to run `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0` and set deployment target as at least iOS 9.0.